# Rearrange NSArray and insert Object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I have an NSMutableArray which has five objects in it. I want to insert an object in the middle of an array, let me say atIndex 1, and move all the objects to index+1 how do I do that?

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `insertObject`

```
NSMutableArray  *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arr insertObject:@"OBJ" atIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

With `insertObject:AtIndex:` method of NSMutableArray.
See [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I didn't know that "If index is already occupied, the objects at index and beyond are shifted by adding 1 to their indices to make room." Thanks for the doc link

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",nil];
[arr insertObject:@"2" atIndex:[arr count]/2];
```